# Using PVC pipe for bathroom exhaust fan duct

Tags: ducts, exhaust-fan

I have to run a length of about 3 meters of duct (from the fan to the outside), where there will be 2 90° bends. I was going to use plastic flexduct, but I can make the bends bends and some of length using 100mm PVC.

Is it worth the hassle of doing pipe work instead of just running flex duct? I live in Brazil, and I don't see much condensation getting trapped for long with our temperatures.

Comment: I think PVC pipe would be better than flex it is smooth and will not leak after years of service like flex can.

Comment: ...and smooth translates to more airflow from the same fan due to less duct resistance. Remember to slope the majority of the pipe downward to the exit for condensation (there will certainly be some in a bathroom duct.)

Comment: If you live in a colder climate, do not slope the pipe towards the outside.  If you live in the US (which obviously the OP does not) check local codes, as most (I believe) require the duct to slope towards the interior not exterior.

Comment: @Tester101, do you know why is that?

Comment: @LuizBorges In colder climates, it's so you don't block the pipe up with ice.  Code wise, it's probably easier to have it always slop in, rather than base the slope direction on location.  US codes cover a wide range of climates.

Comment: Flex duct should generally be avoided everywhere :-) .   BTW, you did make sure that your PVC is 100mm ID and that's what the exhaust fan requires?.

Comment: Yes, I will use PVC pipe from the outside wall up to about a meter from the exhaust fan, this last meter will be flex duct, since it will make it easier to install the fan and do some maintenance.